# Async named pipe, blocking call in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have two applications and I used named pipes to communicate between them. The pipes is working absolutely fine thanks to a code project article. But I noticed that if both the apps don't start. Application 'A' keeps waiting for application 'B' and app 'A' does not start. The following is a snippet which creates an aync pipe:

```
            NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
```

This is the same way I create the pipes in both App 'A' and 'B',each of the applications would have a client as well. This is how I send messages from the client:

```
NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
            // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);

            byte[] _buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr);
            pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, AsyncSend, pipeStream);
```

So how can I improve the performance so that both the applications run without waiting? As of now,I have kept a timeout of 1000 ms. Should I reduce the timeout period? Or am I missing something,which looks likely :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435262/c-asynchronous-namedpipeserverstream-understanding

Comment: both the applications will be on the same machine. WCF creates a local server isn't it?

Comment: WCF server-client infra can be inside Managed application (your regular console/application), can be inside Windows service or IIS, i have built a project that i have 2 processes, both contains WCF services and proxy to communicate with each other. it works very good. but it depend if this is what you need.

Comment: You will have 2 classes - a proxy client class, and a service host class that receive calls from client.. client class in one process, servicehost class in the other, and both project must know the service interface (the operations)

Comment: I did see the namedpipes in WCF but since it was using localhost, I dint want to use it. But let me try it again, if its improving the performance of my application will opt for it :)

Comment: You should use whatever is good for your design. alot of application uses WCF and the internet is full with documentation and samples and also in SO..

Comment: Thanks ilansch for your advice. I had reviewed the WCF for this application but I felt it was unnecessary to host a port through WCF. But let me have a look at it again :)

Comment: SO is much more effective when asking question about WCF.. very helpful